# Terraform executable not discovered by teamcity agent

Tags: docker, makefile, teamcity, terraform

I am writing a teamcity pipeline in which I am using terraform to spin up some AWS instances.
My pipeline uses docker to invoke all steps one by one

However, terraform init keeps failing with terraform: Command not found error

```
[11:05:00][Step 2/6] Initialising terraform
[11:05:00][Step 2/6] terraform init
[11:05:00][Step 2/6] Makefile:41: recipe for target 'terraformApply' failed
[11:05:00][Step 2/6] make: terraform: Command not found
```

Here is the terraformApply snippet of my Makefile

```
    @echo Download terraform
    # ${CURDIR}
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.20/terraform_0.12.20_linux_amd64.zip
    unzip -o terraform_0.12.20_linux_amd64.zip
    @echo Terraform downloaded
    # @echo Current Directory
    # ${CURDIR}
    sleep 60
    @echo *
    @echo Initialising terraform
    terraform init
    ## sudo terraform/terraform plan
    @echo Terraform initialised
    TF_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY="****" TF_VAR_AWS_SECRET_KEY="****" terraform apply -auto-approve
    @echo Terraform setup done
```

My pipeline runs on linux agent.

I ran this Makefile directly on a linux machine, which works fine. However on teamcity pipeline it can't find the extracted terraform.
Also, used `echo *` in Makefile to list all files present in the directory and I do see terraform present in the same path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux-based systems do not search for binaries in current working directory by default. After you have extracted `terraform`, you need to call it as `./terraform init`.

Comment: oh that was silly!! thanks for the suggestion, it worked